# jqGrid local data as XML

Tags: jqgrid

Can I access local XML files as data in jqGrid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can load the contents of the XML file in a string variable and use `datatype: 'xmlstring'` (see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#xml_string). It will work.

Answer (score 1):

I could run a local example using **xmlstring** method after modify the example code that I saw in: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#xml_string

**My modified code is:**

```
var mystr =
"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>"+
"<invoices>"+
    "<rows>"+
        "<row>"+
            "<cell>data1</cell>"+
            "<cell>data2</cell>"+
            "<cell>data3</cell>"+
            "<cell>data4</cell>"+
            "<cell>data5</cell>"+
            "<cell>data6</cell>"+
        "</row>"+
    "</rows>"+
"</invoices>";
```

**Instead of:**

```
var mystr =
"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<invoices>
    <rows>
        <row>
            <cell>data1</cell>
            <cell>data2</cell>
            <cell>data3</cell>
            <cell>data4</cell>
            <cell>data5</cell>
            <cell>data6</cell>    
        </row>
    </rows>
</invoices>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to access an XML file stored on the client's machine via JavaScript? I don't think that can be done.

The more common scenario is pulling your XML via an Ajax call. I'd also look at the "local" option on the [jqGrid wiki](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data). You could embed your data as JSON/XML in the HTML page and read it in when setting up your jqGrid.

Comment: setting the local option means the data has to be an Array. How does it works on a plain XML?